# String.split() generates a NullPointerException

Tags: java, string

String.split() generates a NullPointerException.

```
BufferedReader brs = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String s1;
String s2[];
s1 = brs.readLine();
s2 = s1.split(" ");
```

Comment: Because your `readLine()` returns null.

Comment: From your code and the exception thrown it is obvious that s1 is null. Which brings us to the next conclusion: that brs.readLine(); returns null. You should act accordingly by checking if it is null before calling a method from it. Also, next time provide the stack trace so we can check what went wrong.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

s1 might be `null`,

```
s1 = brs.readLine();
if(s1!=null)
 s2 = s1.split(" ");
```

Answer (score 2):

s1 might be null. Try this.

```
if (s1 != null && !s1.trim().equals(""))
    s2 = s1.split(" ");
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked what's coming from `brs.readLine()`. That is where the `null`-value originates from. Probably the file is empty: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29

Answer (score 1):

if this line throws nullpointer

```
s2 = s1.split(" ");
```

then s1 must be null

check for null before you call EDIT split /EDIT

Note:
**BufferedReader.readLine();
Returns**:
A String containing the contents of the line, not including any line-termination characters, or **null if the end of the stream has been reached**

Answer (score 1):

BufferedReader.readLine() returns null if the end of stream is encountered. See the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29). You should put a null check before you split s1.

Answer (score 0):

Your BufferedReader is definately empty, so readline() returns null. Maybe your input stream is empty.